# Why are these angles the same?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

I'm doing a problem for an hour now because I'm stuck. I decided to look at the solutions and saw this picture. I can't seem to figure out how the theta angles are the same? Can somebody please explain?

Comment: The tangent and the radius are perpendicular. The equality follows from the fact that the unmarked angle of the triangle is equal to $90^\circ - \theta$ and vertical opposite angles near the small triangle at the top.

Comment: @player3236 what do you mean by vertical opposite angles near the small triangle at top?

Comment: In that small triangle, the top unmarked angle is $90^\circ - \theta$ and there is a $90^\circ$ formed with the tangent. The remaining angle must equal $\theta$, and thus is equal to the other angle since they are vertical opposite angles.

Comment: I hope the explanation is clear. If not, I am happy to provide a diagram with marked vertices.

Comment: @player3236 I see it! Thanks a bunch, especially for you willing to provide a diagram as well. Thankfully there is no need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tangents at $A$ and $B$ intersects at point $X$ (just below where the $d$ is on the diagram), then consider the quadrilateral $OAXB$:

$\angle A = \angle B = 90^\circ$ and $\angle O = \theta$, and $\angle O + \angle A + \angle B + \angle X = 360^\circ$, so the external angle of $\angle X$ would also be $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

- Construct the height from point $B$ , can you see which angle is equal to $\theta$?
- To conclude, remember that the triangle is a right one.

Answer (score 0):

Turning the entire figure counterclockwise by $\theta$ moves $OA$ to $OB$ ($O$ is the center of the earth), because the angle between the two lines is $\theta$.

Turning the entire figure counterclockwise by $\theta$ moves "to first sunset" to "to second sunset". Thus the angle between those two lines is also $\theta$.